# How to count unique words in a stream?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Is there a way to count the number of unique words in a stream with Flink Streaming? The results would be a stream of number which keeps increasing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can solve the problem by storing all words which you've already seen. Having this knowledge you can filter out all duplicate words. The rest can then be counted by a map operator with parallelism `1`. The following code snippet does exactly that.

```scala
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

val inputStream = env.fromElements("foo", "bar", "foobar", "bar", "barfoo", "foobar", "foo", "fo")

// filter words out which we have already seen
val uniqueWords = inputStream.keyBy(x => x).filterWithState{
  (word, seenWordsState: Option[Set[String]]) => seenWordsState match {
    case None => (true, Some(HashSet(word)))
    case Some(seenWords) => (!seenWords.contains(word), Some(seenWords + word))
  }
}

// count the number of incoming (first seen) words
val numberUniqueWords = uniqueWords.keyBy(x => 0).mapWithState{
  (word, counterState: Option[Int]) =>
    counterState match {
      case None => (1, Some(1))
      case Some(counter) => (counter + 1, Some(counter + 1))
    }
}.setParallelism(1)

numberUniqueWords.print();

env.execute()
```

Comment: Can it cause OOM or performance degradation if incoming stream is "infinity" and set of strings (in `filterWithState`) becoming too big?

Comment: Not if you're using a state backend which supports out-of-core. The `RocksDBStateBackend` is such a state backend. If you use the memory state backend, then you have to clear the state once in a while, otherwise you might run into OOM.

Comment: Yet one question, as I understand the save/restore operations to/from `RocksDBStateBackend` backend in this case has complexity O(N) where N is count of elements in set i.e. this backend always save/restore all elements of Set or only changed elements?

Comment: This implementation uses the `ValueState` abstraction which would always save/restore the complete `Set`. However, one could probably also use the `ListState` abstraction to make the checkpointing incremental.

Comment: Hi Till, is `filterWithState` only available in version 1.1? I couldn't find it in Flink 1.0.0.

Comment: The `filterWithState` method is part of Flink's Scala API since version 1.0.0. However, it is only applicable to `KeyedStreams`. This means you have to call first `keyBy` on a stream.